# How to print an array value below was evaluated just now

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array. But I can't print that array at all. I am almost madly for this type of array behaviour. Please help me how to print that array.

[image: My Array]

It seems to be an empty array. But It is an array. When I click that array I see that result.

[image]

When I move cursor the icon `i` it gives me a message.

**value below was evaluated just now**

This is my code

```
var selectedVal = [];

$('body').on('click', '.carat ', function () {
    $(".single-progress-mark").show();
    $('.carat ').removeClass("active");

    $(this).addClass("active");
    var det = $(this).attr('data-attr-details');
    async: false;
    $('.Carat1').text(det);
    selectedVal.push({
        Carat : det
    });
});

console.log(selectedVal);
```

This is my `console.log` output. But I want to print **0.30**. I want many ways to print that.

like `console.log(selectedVal[0].carat);` or `console.log(selectedVal[0]['carat']);` It always gives me `undefined` or error.

So please help me how to print my desired output **0.30**

Comment: What happens when you put `console.log(selectedVal)` inside the body click event at last?

Comment: You need to move the console.log into the click handler function

Comment: @palaѕн Then It shows the correct answer. But I need this out of the click function

Comment: You can't because you are basically asking. I need to display a user name in the console log which is saved in the database before I could even make an ajax call to fetch the data.

Comment: @palaѕн But I get the result out of the click handler. But how do I print this value. Please some suggestion if alternative way

Comment: There is no way other than moving the console.log into the click handler function. For more info check: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve this problem by help of @palash advice

```
$('body').on('click', '.carat ', function () {
    $(".single-progress-mark").show();
    $('.carat ').removeClass("active");

    $(this).addClass("active");
    var det = $(this).attr('data-attr-details');
    async: false;
    $('.Carat1').text(det);
    var selectedVal = [];
    selectedVal.push({
        Carat : det
    });
    passValue(selectedVal);
});
```

And in my function I get this value

```
function passValue(passParameter){
    console.log(passParameter[0].Carat);
}
```